# Python errors occurring trying to insert data into a MySQL database table

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I need to create an sql login/ sign up system for my program, however I keep hitting this error no matter what I do to change it. I need to have a randomly generated UTID, the users first and surname, along with a password that is verified, then the UserID is generated by taking the first three letters of the first name and the whole surname. I cant figure out how to overcome this.

I have tried to give the values inside the sql statement when inserting some literal datatypes, like writing " 
    c.execute('insert INTO tbl_Teachers (str(UTID), str(FName), str(SName), str(userPass), str(userID))VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);', var_insert) " but nothing seems to work.

```
def signup():
    name = []
    surname = []
    print("Please enter the following details.")
    user_type = str(input("Are you a teacher or a student: "))
    if user_type == ("teacher") or ("Teacher"):
        var_FName = str(input("First Name: "))
        var_LName = str(input("Last Name: "))
        var_password1 = str(input("Choose a password: "))
        var_password2 = str(input("Please confirm password: "))
        UTID = str(random.randint(0,100000))
        print ("Your UserID is "+UTID+"")
        name.append(var_FName)
        surname.append(var_LName)
        userID = []
        for x in range (0, 3):
            userID.append(var_FName[x])
        for x in range (0,len(var_LName)):
            userID.append(var_LName[x])
        print (userID)
        if var_password1 != var_password2:
            print("Please try again.")

        else:

            var_insert = []
            var_insert.append(UTID)
            var_insert.append(var_FName)
            var_insert.append(var_LName)
            var_insert.append(str(var_password1))
            var_insert.append(userID)
            conn = sqlite3.connect('Program.db')
            c = conn.cursor()
            c.execute('insert INTO tbl_Teachers (UTID, FName, SName, userPass, userID)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);', var_insert)
            conn.commit()

InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 4 - probably unsupported type.
```

Comment: `userID` is a list, you can't store a list in a database column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`userID` is supposed to be a string, but you're creating a list. Use string concatenation, not the `append` method.

```
userID = var_FName[0:3] + var_LName
```